# Do Star Wars characters ever read for entertainment?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the Star Wars universe, it seems there is a multitude of myths and fables passed down by oral tradition.

We also know books exist, such as the Jedi texts in *The Last Jedi*, but the ones in that example are nonfiction/instructional books.

Are there any examples of fictional written texts in Star Wars canon or Legends that characters read purely for entertainment?

Are there people who make a living as fiction writers?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Authors

Comment: @Valorum I picked a couple of pages at random from the list and it didn't appear they wrote _fiction_.  (Except to the extent that any report contains slantings of the truth to make the author look better. :)

Comment: Actually is there any fiction depicted _at all_ in the SW universe?  Any movies?  Epic poems?  I haven't read a lot of Legends stuff, but I don't really recall anyone watching a video, or talking about doing so...

Comment: @DavidW Yes, quite a bit actually, but only mentioned indirectly in most cases. Poetry, opera, and quite a few other forms of media that are inherently at least partially fictional are mentioned multiple times, as are various myths, legends, and tall tales. We rarely ever see such things in detail though because modern preferences force embedded narratives to either be comprehensive (like _The Princess Bride_) or short and concise (like most of the force visions in _Star Wars_, or Palpatine relating the story of Darth Plageius to Anakin in Episode III), especially in visual media.

Comment: In the original film Luke refers to being teleported off Tattooine. Since matter transportation doesn't exist in the Star Wars universe this must be a fictional concept from their equivalent of a science fiction or fantasy story.

Comment: Page-turners the novels in _Star Wars_ are not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes!**

In Legends continuity, there are several examples of characters reading books for entertainment, whether fiction or otherwise.

Per the real-world book [*Boba Fett: The Fight to Survive*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_The_Fight_to_Survive), Boba Fett was known to be an avid reader as a child on Kamino. He would often check out books from the local extension of the [Tipoca City library](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tipoca_City_library_branch), which was little more than a slot in the wall occupied by a library droid. While his father Jango encouraged his son to read "important" things such as maps, manuals, and schematics (which he did), Boba also enjoyed reading fiction as an escape from his monotonous life on Kamino. None of the books are mentioned by title or in particular detail, but Boba's interest in reading is brought up multiple times in the early chapters.

Also, the Solo twins Jacen and Jaina were fond of a bedtime story called [*The Little Lost Bantha Cub*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Little_Lost_Bantha_Cub), preferring the way their father Han Solo would read it to them over C-3PO's rendition.